# Getting network traffic after click

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my work place I've been ask to build a selenium automation script that capture the site network traffic after my script made a click action.

[This is the details they want to get back from the automation (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOSkB.png)

does any one can direct me how to capture this information ?
i'm using python 3.7 with Chromedriver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't sniff data, but use it to trigger for instance https://github.com/dugsong/pypcap.